# Register Site User and Send Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-applications, passwords

What is the best way to register the user for the website and send a link with user name and password?

Admin will create the user by entering user name but not password

The password needs to be generated and stored as a hash text in database and send the same to user's email with link and user name. (Here I cant reverse the hash text back to plain text and send to in email) :(

How can i achieve this? I stored some random text in a hashed format in database. Not sure how I will email to the user, whenever admin create a new user.

Any idea/articles or suggestion?

Comment: You need to generate the random password, store a hashed version to the database, make sure the INSERT was successful. Then send the original un-hashed random password to the user, whilst you still know what it is.

Comment: @diggersworld that sound good. When user login i need to force them to set a new password :)

Comment: @diggersworld, what will happen if email sending failed :( how do i send an email again?

Comment: Well if it fails that's just one of those things. Your site should have a forgotten password area. Which will allow the user to reset it. Basically you would create a new password with the reset function, email it to the registered address, then ask them to change it when they login again.

Comment: I've written a full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I don't like the sending passwords in plain text. However I can understand why it is sometimes required. For example an admin creating an account for a user.

**Sending the initial email with credentials**

When the user is registered with the website. Save the email address and randomly generated password (hashed) to the database. On successful INSERT send the email to the user with the original randomly generated password (not the hashed one).

**If the email fails**

If the email fails to send or reach the recipient, or they delete it, then they've lost the password. Your site will need a forgotten password section where the user can request it to be reset. On performing this action your script will create another random generated password, store the hashed version to the database and send the unhashed version to the user.

It's a good idea to separate the reset password from the main account details in case it wasn't the owner who tried to reset it. Otherwise when they come to login their known password will no longer work because the reset password would have overwritten it.

**Change password on login**

In both scenarios the user should be forced to change password on login.

**Additional Options**

If you wanted you could store a timestamp along with the account credentials for how long they have to reset or login for the first time. If the login request with the emailed credentials is within that time then you allow them access. If it is not then you say sorry credentials expired and allow them to reset again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `authentication` for admin login and giving him authority to create new logins.

You can get help about `authentication and authorizations` over here>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/eeyk640h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

and

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization

**And you can simply use this function to send Email>>**

```
public int sendMail(string to,string cc,string bcc,string subject,string body)

{ 

    try 

        {  


       SmtpMail.SmtpServer="your_server_address"; 

       MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(); 

            msg.From = "your_email_id";

       msg.To = to; 

            msg.Cc = cc; 

            msg.Bcc = bcc; 

            msg.Subject = subject; 

            msg.Body = body; 

       SmtpMail.Send(msg); 

            return(1); 
        } 
        catch 
        { 
               return (0); 
        } 
}
```

**On SendEmail Button Click>>**

```
private void Button1_ServerClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
    String to = “to_email_id”; 
    String cc = “cc_email_id”; 
    String bcc = “bcc_email_id”; 
    String subject = “your subject goes here”; 
    String body = “your body text goes here”; 

    int status = sendMail(to,cc,bcc,subject,body); 

    if(status == 1) 
        Response.Write("your mail has been sent successfully"); 
    else 
        Response.Write("sorry! your mail could not be sent”); 
}
```

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Oh my god. I dont think you understand my question. I know sending email and authentication. I would like to know better way of doing, like using nonce technique, etc